# Custom Resequencer Behaviour

Tags: spring-integration

I have an scenario where I must send messages in order to a rest service and I plan to use a resequencer. The behaviour of this resequencer must be:

- Order messages by time in day (hh:mm:ss): data on the message
- Release messages only after they stay a period of time in the bus (p.e. 2 minutes)

As the default Resequencer didn't serve for this purpose I decided to develop a custom one changing the ResequencerMessageGroupProcessor for a CustomResequencerMessageGroupProcessor.

I succeded using a service activator but I had to explictly define the output-channel as a property. Isn't there a way to use the output-channel attribute on the xml declaration?

When I use the output-channel attribute the following error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no outputChannel or replyChannel header   available
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.sendReplies(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:616)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:597)
at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:405)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
... 46 more
```

here's my example:

```
<int:channel id="resequencerChannel"/>


<int:service-activator id="customResequencer" ref="resequencingMessageHandler" 
        input-channel="resequencerChannel" />

<int:channel id="aggregatedMessageChannel" />

<bean id="resequencingMessageHandler" class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.ResequencingMessageHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="releaseStrategy"  ref="timeoutReleaseStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg name="processor" ref="customResequencerMessageGroupProcessor"/>
    <constructor-arg name="store" ref="redisMessageStore"/>
    <constructor-arg name="correlationStrategy" ref="customCorrelationStrategy"/>
    <property name="outputChannel" ref="aggregatedMessageChannel"/>
    <property name="sendPartialResultOnExpiry" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customResequencerMessageGroupProcessor" class="test.resequencer.CustomResequencerMessageGroupProcessor">
    <constructor-arg name="timeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="timeoutReleaseStrategy" class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy" >
    <constructor-arg name="threshold" value="100000"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="timeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customCorrelationStrategy" class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy" >
    <constructor-arg name="attributeName" value="correlationId"/>
```

Also, if you think there is a better way to do this, please, I would apreciatte telling so

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Guzman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing (`ref`) a `MessageHandler` from a `<service-activator/>` the XML `output-channel` is only applied if the referenced handler is an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` (ARPMH).

Components such as routers, aggregators, resequencers, are not considered to be ARPMHs because they sometimes produce a reply, sometimes don't and, in the case of a router, might produce multiple "replies" which doesn't fit the service activator model.

We could probably refactor the aggregator/resequencer to be ARPMHs because they only produce 0 or 1 "reply". We could also add some smarts to the `ServiceActivatorFactoryBean` to inject the output channel if the reference is an `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler`. Feel free to open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

In the meantime, your solution is the correct work-around.

Comment: Hi Gary! thank you very much for your quick answer and comments. I'll do it this way.